# One div appear on click and second closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

i know simple java script function on click

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
    $(".fade", this).fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

but i want that on click one div appears and second one closes . like on this page http://www.wpbeginner.com/free-wordpress-blog-setup/, but on viewing source i could not find any code . Don't worry this link doesn't belong to me or my website

Comment: the link doesn't serve much purpose as you're not even pointing out which part does it... your explanation is otherwise quite clear, unless I have misunderstood it...

Comment: after having mine selected first, you selected the other answer as the correct one for no reason I can understand, other than you didn't like my comment... the 2 are basically the same, except mine is shorter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should do it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click').click(function(){
        if ($('.first').is(':visible')) {
            $('.first').css('display', 'none');
            $('.second').fadeIn(2000);
        } else {
            $('.second').css('display', 'none');
            $('.first').fadeIn(2000);
        }
    });                  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/57VaZ/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html looks something like this:

```
<a class="click">click</a><br />
<a class="fade1">fade1</a><br />
<a class="fade2">fade2</a><br />
```

Make sure the one that you want to show on click is hidden by default:

```css
.fade2 { display:none }
```

Then do the following in jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
    $(".fade1, .fade2").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

**[Here is a fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5hMzk/)**

Comment: hey your code is quite clear , but i am asking i have 2 button . Anchor a , b and c , and div c,d,f intailly. none of the is visible , when i click a only a should open , if i click it 2 nd time it should not be displayed and if i click second anchor 2 should open and 1 st get closed . For a demo you can check http://www.wpbeginner.com/free-wordpress-blog-setup/ , and take example of two button i want free blog setup and i need convincing

Comment: why would you accept the answer then repeat your question (even less clear actually) in a comment? that doesn't make much sense to me... if you can't make use of such simple code as what I provided (or @user3631948's for that matter), then you're in big trouble...